# Grails bootstrap file upload plugin completion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails, plugins

I'm relatively new to web development (doing C++ back-end stuff for decades) and am jumping into the groovy/grails paradigm.  I'm using a fantastic plugin called Grails Bootstrap File Upload plugin (https://github.com/sarbogast/grails-bootstrap-file-upload/blob/master/README.md).

I've integrated the plugin into my form and all is well except I'd like to trigger a "cleanup and moveon" function when all files have successfully uploaded.  So, something like:

1. User fills out forms & validate (check)
2. User adds files (check)
3. User upload files (check)
4. I validate various things about the files and then redirect to a processing monitor screen (not checked!)

Another note is that the plugin allows you to load all the files as one push (which I can't seem to get to work) or sequentially, which looks better to me and I'd prefer.

Does anyone have any experience with this plugin or some general advice on how one can find out when the files have all been successfully loaded?  Something as simple as knowing when I was processing the last file in my controller action would give me enough...

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual jquery plugin's documentation is better than the grails plugin's documentation, and I discovered a whole slew of callback functions that are available via javascript: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

The following code snippet worked perfectly for my needs:

```
<script>
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadstop', function (e) {
        <g:remoteFunction action="finishUpdate" id="${fileSubmissionInstance.uniqueName}" update="updateMe" />
    }) 
</script>
```